# Store certificate file on Travis

Tags: macos, certificate, travis-ci, keychain, p12

I am developing complete automate build using Travis CI for macOS application. As part of build I need to sign my bundle. Currently since I need to create keychain and store my certificate there it is stored on my code repository.

For security reasons I would like to avoid storing the certificate file on the repository but I think it is not possible to store it on Travis and make it available for each build. Is that possible?

Also what other alternatives would I have. Could anyone give some ideas?

Thanks in advance and regards

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yep i was able using travis feature

Comment: Can you please add it as an answer. Was searching for the same. It would be really helpful if you could.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide on Travis doc explaining the process. It might be useful for someone

[Travis doc](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/)